# Making plotly subplots using both colspan and rowspan

Tags: plotly, panel

I am trying to make subplots using plotly.make_subplots. I need a layout like this:\

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 |

where

1: lineplot
2: boxplot
3: null_values
4: pie chart
5: q-q plot

For a better understanding of what I wanted to achieve, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQdLd.png)

This is the layout that I want in the plot..

Each number in the above layout description is the continuation of the respective plot. eg: I dont want different lineplots on each place with '1', but i want the lineplot to be continued to all the areas marked 1.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    fig = make_subplots(rows=5,
                    cols=5,
                    horizontal_spacing=0.01,
                    vertical_spacing=0.05,
                    specs=[[{'colspan': 5, 'rowspan': 2}, None, None, None, None],
                           [None, None, None, None, None],
                           [{'colspan': 4,}, None, None, None, {'rowspan': 3}],
                           [{'colspan': 2, 'rowspan': 2, 'type': 'pie'}, None, {'colspan': 2, 'rowspan': 2}, None, None],
                           [None, None, None, None, None]],
                    subplot_titles=['Lineplot', 'Boxplot', 'Null values', 'Pie chart', 'Q-Q Plot'],
                    shared_xaxes=False,
                    shared_yaxes=False)

    fig.add_trace(plots['lineplot'].data[0], row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(plots['lineplot'].layout.xaxis, row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(plots['lineplot'].layout.yaxis, row=1, col=1)

    fig.add_trace(plots['boxplots'].data[0], row=3, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(plots['boxplots'].layout.xaxis, row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(plots['boxplots'].layout.yaxis, row=2, col=1, side='left')

    fig.add_trace(plots['piechart'].data[0], row=4, col=1)  # Corrected row and col values
    fig.update_xaxes(plots['piechart'].layout.xaxis, row=4, col=1)  # Corrected row and col values
    fig.update_yaxes(plots['piechart'].layout.yaxis, row=4, col=1, side='left')  # Corrected row and col values

    fig.add_trace(plots['qq_plot'].data[0], row=4, col=3)
    fig.update_xaxes(plots['qq_plot'].layout.xaxis, row=3, col=3)
    fig.update_yaxes(plots['qq_plot'].layout.yaxis, row=3, col=3, side='left')

    fig.add_trace(plots['null_values'].data[0], row=3, col=5)
    fig.update_xaxes(plots['null_values'].layout.xaxis, row=3, col=5)  # Corrected row and col values
    fig.update_yaxes(plots['null_values'].layout.yaxis, row=3, col=5, side='left')  # Corrected row and col values

    # Set layout properties
    fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800)

    # Display the chart
    fig.show()
```

Here, `plots` is a dict containing many plotly graph objects.(plotly.graph_objects.Figure())\

For some reason, my plots appear weird

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZnSc.png)

Please help me get subplots aligned in the particular format.

My end goal is to serve it as a panel app

`pn.serve(fig)`